# return response result of following mongoose's schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've been using node (express) with mongoose for a while but I have little clue about mongoose's schema. What I know is it throw you an error and prevent you to do any db operation if the request object (like req.body.firstName) you pass is not exist in the schema.

How can I return my api result according the schema? for example I have a schema like this

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        first: {
            type: String
        },
        last: {
            type: String
        }
}

module.exports.getAllUsers = (callback) => {
    User.find({}, (err,result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
}
```

I might not get `first` and `last` property in my array, I get whatever data that store in the users collection.

Does it means every response I have to manually do

```
res.json({
   first,
   last
})
```

I'm looking an option to return response that will follow mongoose's schema.

Comment: What are you actually asking/saying? Is it that not all of the documents in your collection actually have **both** the `"first"` and `"last"` properties and you want all returned data to show both whether it's stored that way or not? OR Are you instead asking *"Why is it stored this way and does not have **both**?"*. Because it's really unclear which of those ( or anything else ) that you are actually asking.

Comment: You define the schema, but doesnt show where do you create your model. Also you never invoke the "callback". You question is quite unclear to me.